# iphone dealloc property

Tags: ios, instance, dealloc

I run the analyse build on Xcode, and get a warning for a leak because of an object that is a property and instance var

.h

```
UIView *_transparentView; }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *transparentView;
```

.m

```
@synthesize transparentView = _transparentView;


self.transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:transparentViewFrame];

- (void)dealloc {
[_transparentView release];
```

so I release the ivar on dealloc, but how to release the property?, [self.transparentview release] ??

Comment: You are responsible for 2 retains: 1 for the alloc and 1 for the property (retain attribute), but you are doing just 1 release. You could add an autorelease to self.transparentView = ... to be clean.

Comment: Or just assign the alloc'd object directly to _transparentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom has answered replace the line that assigns the "transparentView" with:

```
self.transparentView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:transparentViewFrame] autorelease];
```

when you any value to a retained property you should you should release the assigned value if you are done with it, and release the property when deallocating the class.